# how to speed up the feature and role lists in 2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008

On every 2008 server I've worked on, it takes many seconds to populate the "list of features" or the "list of roles" that the server has.  Is there some way to speed this up?  Perhaps by having it populate the list on boot up?

For example, just trying to get to the UI for working with queues in MSMQ takes forever, waiting for the server to realize that it is indeed an MSMQ server, to give me the option to click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for corruption in the Roles/Features catalog by following the directions in this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2461206

To be honest, though, loading up Roles or Features is just not a quick process. You may just want to use the administrative tool for MSMQ instead of going through the Roles in Server Manager.

Comment: Hyppy - I'm gonna hold out a bit, hoping that someone will provide some undocumented fix or something that will make it load faster :)  otherwise I'll accept your answer.  thanks!

Comment: wow nothing better going on - thanks Hyppy!  and no thx MS!